# Apply shadow on hidden svg path

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

Here is [pen](https://codepen.io/bumbeishvili/pen/LyOOOz)

I want to apply drop shadow effect on rect, when rect is hidden using one of the following technique:

```
opacity:0 // or  
fill:rgba(1,1,1,0)  // or  
fill-opacity:0  // or  
display:none
```

when I trying to apply filter on such elements, shadow not appearing at all...

Is it possible to apply drop shadow on hidden Svg paths? How?

Comment: How can something that's invisible cast a shadow?

Comment: I have updated pen, I wan't to show elements under that rect, but also want outside rect to have shadows

I don't know how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is by using a mask.

In the demo below we have added a drop shadow to a circle.  Then we construct the mask so that it hides the circle itself, but keeps the area outside the circle (ie the shadow).  Revealing the red rectangle behind it.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="8" stdDeviation="4"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="invisible">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="80" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <rect x="40" y="60" width="150" height="80" fill="red"/>

  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="80"
      style="fill:blue; filter:url(#shadow); mask: url(#invisible);"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a drop shadow with no rect, setting the fill to the background color will work:

```
.square{
  fill:#fff;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  filter:url('#drop-shadow');
}
```

If you've got multiple elements under the rect, you could try hiding just the filled in area with a [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) or [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask).

Comment: yes, I have multiple elements under the rect, and I want to see them

Comment: I will try using clip-path and will see if what I want can be achieved

Comment: I have accepted Paul's answer because of demo :) thank you too